# React Native Component not re-rendering despite render function running

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rendering, react-redux

I am a little baffled here ..

I have some code like this

```
renderTopic(topic){
    if(topic.isMine){console.log('work?')}
        return (
            <View key={topic.id.toString()} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addToic.call(this, topic)} >
                    {topic.isMine && <Topic topic={topic} active={true}/>}
                    {!topic.isMine && <Topic topic={topic} active={false}/>}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }

render() {
    console.log("re-rendering", this.props.myTopics)
    return (
        <View style={s.welcome}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={s.topics}>
                    {this.props.me.myTopics.map(topic => this.renderTopic(topic) )}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
        )
    }
```

The problem is when I update topics using the traditional redux -> 'dispatch action' method, the re-render function fires, the should component update function fires, everything looks like it works but the `topic.isMine` conditional rendering never updates and switches the components over.

The correct result is displayed if I change page, the app then re-renders correctly.

Comment: can you provide the connect part and the reducer part so we can see it? The problem is either on you passing data from Reducer to component or for the component to read the data from the state

Answer (score 0):

Probably your reducer does not create new `topic` object. React sees, that reference to new topic matches old topic and skips calling `renderTopic(topic)` with same reference value as before.

Comment: Thank you for your response but .. renderTopic is definitely being called and with the correct data. I have added logging in it.